# SQL query date/number list

Tags: sql, list, date, numbers

I have the following query in my own photo database:

```
select distinct left(Nr, 8) as Date, Ort from Fotos where Typ='D' order by left(Nr, 8) desc, Ort
```

Where Nr is a unique string as date + a hyphen + a sequential number in the form yyyymmdd-xxx.
Ort is a string, the location of the photo.

This works fine so far and I get a list like this:

```
20220717    Lindabrunn, Symposion
20220717    Feistritzsattel 
20220717    Pernitz, Schärfthal
20220715    Mannswörth
20220715    Wienerbergteich
20220715    Zentralfriedhof
20220712    V
20220710    Himberg
```

But what I really want is the first Nr for a date and a location like this:

```
20220717-001    Lindabrunn, Symposion
20220717-045    Feistritzsattel
20220717-103    Pernitz, Schärfthal
20220715-001    Mannswörth
20220715-009    Wienerbergteich
20220715-033    Zentralfriedhof
20220712-001    V   
20220710-001    Himberg
```

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: Where does the `sequential number` come from? what are the rules of generating it (why did you have 045 for the second row, for example)? Also, why do you need to use DISTINCT; if you generate a sequence they will all be unique and distinct will not do anything?

Comment: I generate the sequential number by myself. Every photo has a "Nr" that ist unique and is a string with date + hyphen + that sequential number.
-045 should be the result of the query. -001 till -044 have the same date and location, -045 is the first where date or location is different.
I use DISTINCT for Date (= first 8 characters of NR) and Ort (location).
Remember the 2 data tables are NOT the data but the result of the quer!